# Horizontal scroll overlaps code block in Chrome

Tags: bug, google-chrome, osx

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10838510) has a single row code block that is completely obscured by a horizontal scroll bar.

[image]

**EDIT:** After signing in (and reloading the page), this returned to its normal (correct?) behaviour. It only obscures the content while scrolling.

[image]

AFAICT this appears to be an inconsistency in Chrome. But perhaps some more padding could be added so that the code is visible even while scrolling?

**EDIT 2:** Perhaps this is to do with this system setting in OSX (available via Preferences > General):

[image]

Comment: what version of Chrome? i'm using 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit) and [i don't see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUkPb.png) however your scrollbar looks different to mine

Comment: I just signed in (refreshing the page) and this problem disappeared. I've seen this kind of inconsistent scroll bar in Chrome before (on various computers). Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Also Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)

Comment: @Memor-X looks like tablet/touch mode... I don't see it either.

Comment: This is on OSX, so the correct behaviour is the scrollbar should appear/disappear when interacted with via a touch interface or mouse wheel. However when I loaded this page it was there permanently. I've seen this exact same thing on Stack before a couple of times.

Comment: It happens when the cursor is over the scroll bar and you scroll horizontally. Happens in other pages too. I just set my OSX preferences to always show the scroll bar. Not the best solution, but it is better to see the scroll bar at all times than to have it hiding the content.

Comment: Related: [One-line codeblock scrollbars won't disappear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326473/4642212)