# Single-line code blocks are unreadable, blocked by horizontal scroll bar

Tags: bug

For example, in Chrome, on code blocks that are a single line, the scroll bar will not go away after it has appeared, and it looks like the following:

[image]

And here's an actual example (bug reproduced in Chrome, haven't tried other browsers):

```
geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationFromEuler( new THREE.Vector3( Math.PI / 2, Math.PI, 0 ) ) );
```

(That example came from *[Three.js, the lookAt function issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675958/three-js-the-lookat-function-issue/17676396#17676396)*.)

The scroll bar never goes away and makes it unreadable.

Comment: What OS are you experiencing this on?

Comment: @Makoto edited, added a link

Comment: @Xufox yeah, looks like the same issue

Comment: @Xufox:  That was *years* ago though.  Question would be why it's manifest *now*.

Comment: @Makoto I don’t know, but it doesn’t seem to be specific to Stack Overflow. The more recent [The scroll bar on the code snippet makes the code unreadable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378033/4642212) has the same solution.

Comment: @Xufox I don't always want to show my scroll bar though. Maybe defensive padding can be added at bottom of code blocks?

Comment: @Xufox Based on that question's answer, I tried it in Finder, and the scroll bar DOES go away after moving away. Just in Chrome is stays. Maybe it is a Chrome bug. In any case, it would be easy to add a small padding to code snippets, regardless of OS/browser issue.

Comment: @Xufox I think this is a StackOverflow bug. I don't have this problem on other sites, only on StackOverflow

Comment: @Makoto ^ For example, I can't reproduce the problem on this code snippet on GitHub: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/14213 Try scrolling horizontally, hover on the scroll bar, then unhover, and it goes away just fine. I recall only ever having this problem on SO.