# Add padding to the code display block for Chrome on Mac

Tags: feature-request, bug

I get a horizontal scrollbar in Chrome 71 on Mac when the code exceeds the box and is on a singe line (or even 2 or more lines). While this is the expected behaviour, what is not is that the scrollbar refusing to disappear 
even when not in focus and most pertinently overlapping the content on the last line.

Some additional padding should help, I guess. I'm not sure if this is the same behaviour on other OSes and versions.

I am able to reproduce it in the answer preview block so I have attached it as a visual reference to the problem:

[image: two lines of code and a horizontal scrollbar covers the bottom of the lower line]

Comment: [One-line codeblock scrollbars won't disappear](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326473/4642212)

Comment: Just be nice and don't post code that requires horizontal scroll.