# Scroll bar overlaps the flag prompt

Tags: bug, osx

Steps to reproduce:

- Goto a question which has code blocks (which is rare nowadays) and is long enough for a scroll bar
- Open the flag prompt and drag that prompt to the scrollbar, the code block has

This happens. The question on the [main site is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55325788/how-to-stop-loading-extra-rows-in-sqlite)

[image: this is a bug]

The device is MacOS and my browser is chrome. Latest. This behavior is on safari too.

Test it here. Noise alert. Not valid javascript

```
const query const query const query const query const query const query const query const query const query const query const query const query const query const query const query const query const query const query const query const query const query
```

The fix can be just this

```css
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
transform: translateZ(0);
```

OR

```css
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

This is a strange bug in macOS. Here is [the relevant thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874546/strange-z-index-behavior-with-scrollbars-under-chrome)

**UPDATE**: This happens for the notification view on the main site too.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this with Chrome or Firefox on Windows.

Comment: Because the scroll bars are a little weird in mac. @Stijn even a default button tag is different from a mac one in windows

Comment: Seems to be fine for me on macOS 10.14.4 and Chrome 75.0.3770.100

Comment: The linked thread is about OS X 10.8 (Mountain Line) released in 2012. Are you also using an ancient version?

Comment: No, I'm using MacOS Mojave 10.14.5 (18F132) @Turnip

Comment: Possibly related (OS X scroll bar issue): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326473/215552

Comment: Could repro (this one and the one linked by @HereticMonkey) on macOS 10.12 with "Show scroll bars" System Prefs set to "When scrolling". Having it to "Auto..." will repro only the current bug, if I do actively scroll while the popup is shown. Having it set to "Always", the bug doesn't kick in. And [according to this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=582932) that could even be a non-retina only issue...

Comment: @Kaiido this can be fixed by just adding a 3D plane transform. Because this starts a graphics engine in the browser for higher processing

Comment: @Kaiido no it doesn’t consumes that much memory that you think. I’ve worked on some iOS related websites and knew that bug, doing translate will solve other problems too. GPU will not be used as that much because we are just using it for a scrollbar. We are not running GOW 4 on ultra

Comment: No repro on Mojave (10.14.5) using FF 65.0.2.

Comment: Could repro on macOS 10.14.5 + Chrome 75.0.3770.100. No repro on FF 67.0.4. Happens with the close prompt too.

Comment: I can repro it with Safari on 10.14.5, but only if I scroll in the box with the trackpad after I open the dialog.

Comment: From the look of it, this isn't a bug in our code, isn't even a bug in Chrome... It's some sort of weird bug in MacOS itself. Probably not gonna get fixed until Apple fixes it.

Comment: @Shog9 it doesn’t happens on firefox in macOS. It can be fixed with just one css line. Why not do it? Just suggesting

Comment: How you tried your code to solve the problem by editing html in the inspect tab? Does it solve when adding the appropriate code?

Comment: @Lighteninger of cource. It works that’s why I’m suggesting. Also you can try it now. It’s a pre tag

Comment: @weegee would probably be better to apply it on the `.popup` class, will work the same while affecting a lot less users. Note that your workaround is actually not without other side-effects: When you do force the new stack context, the browser can't use sub-pixel antialiasing for the text., it will get forced to use transparency antialiasing, which doesn't render as well as sub-pixel. Here are screenshots [without](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlqNz.png) and [with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TePNC.png) from my non-retina screen, but I guess on a retina the difference will only be more noticeable.

Answer (score -8):

Not able to reproduce using MacOS Mojave (10.14.5) using FireFox (65.0.2).

[image]

Also opened the same question you used on the main site:

[image]

Comment: It's a Chrome bug, so it's normal you can't repro on Firefox.

Comment: @Kaiido I wonder were that information came from. As nothing in the comments point to that being the issue. Some even can't repro on Chrome.

Comment: @Luuklang it is a chrome macOS only issue. See this bug report https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=582932 and happens in safari too

Comment: You can upload images without posting an answer. Just upload them in the answer box and then copy the links to your comment.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I know, but that requires people to open the actual link, which I always find annoying myself, so I'll save other the ordeal.

Comment: I'm using Safari 12.1.1 on MacOS 10.14.5 Mojave, and it happens here as well, so no, it's not a Chrome only issue, weegee, @Kaiido. You're wrong.

Comment: @Andreas read the question it's been established it also happens on Safari. If you prefer it's a webkit bug. weegee's "only" was for "macOs only" as in linux and win versions of Chrome don't suffer from this bug.